# Update String Columns without Using Single Quotations - General Question

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, dml

```
UPDATE CustomerPhone 
SET PhoneTypeID = 7, PhoneNumber = 999-444
WHERE CustomerID = 500 AND PhoneNumber = 9-1-1;
```

PhoneNumber is of type varchar(20) whereas PhoneTypeID and CustomerID are of type int. I'm running the above statement in SQL Server, it works fine.

I wonder how come it works? I thought any string value has to be put between '...'

Comment: Try to put in PhoneNumber column a text like "asdasd". Does it still work?

Comment: @peace: what value was actually inserted.... string value `9-1-1` or `7`? I'd expect `7`.

Comment: The performance is inconsistent. It used to work, now i keep getting an error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ....

Comment: @peace: you'll get that error when the data in the column can't be silently converted or casted to the datatype that you pass on the righthand side of the `=` in your WHERE clause. Sounds like you have some data is cannot be coerced into a number.

Comment: By the way! 9-1-1, gives me 7...You were right...

Comment: The problem is, i'm generating the update code from an application, so i was wondering should i put ' or not. This can cause overhead if i have alot of columns of mixed datatype.

Comment: Ok now i got it. Actually, i'm grabbing the phone numbers from text fields, thus, the values are converted to string implicitly from the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server will `CAST` or `CONVERT` the value that you pass it, when you specify a value that isn't of type that you expect.

i.e. Try:
      `SELECT * FROM CustomerPhone WHERE PhoneTypeID = '7'`

Here SQL Server will take your string `'7'` and try to convert to the appropriate type of int, smallint, tinyint (whatever appropriate).

Comment: SELECT * FROM CustomerPhone WHERE PhoneTypeID = '7'

Worked fine!